# Any way to reward contributors beyond upvotes and bounties?

Tags: support, bounties, up-votes

Stack Overflow has been one of my best sources to gain knowledge on JavaScript.

Some answers have been exceptionally helpful - eye opening - and I'd like to know if there's a way to reward the authors beyond upvotes and bounties.

Comment: Not really. That is kind of the "currency" of SO if you will. Did you have something particular in mind?

Comment: A few intrepid users out there list Amazon.com wishlists on their profiles.

Comment: Don't, btw, "thank" someone by going and upvoting a bunch of their other answers. That's called "serial upvoting", and will usually be detected by the system and undone.

Comment: @Bart I was thinking about donations. Some contributors have their own website with a donate button, but I was wondering if there was a way that could apply to anybody.

Comment: @Michael excellent points, thanks! I am afraid I am going to upvote all your comments ;-)

Comment: If the person want to be contacted he usually would leave contact details in his/her profile. Use them to ask him directly, I'm sure many won't mind some hard coin. :)

Comment: other than amazon books I accept bitcoins as well

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best way a student can reward his/her master is by becomming a master himself.

So keep contributing by asking great questions and giving great answers.

Comment: +1, though I do wish you'd put a "young grasshopper" in there.

Comment: +1 It always pleases me when I see after a few months, a user who's shown up initially with dozens of questions capitalize that by turning around to become a prolific and helpful answerer.

Comment: no other answer to this question is necessary